# CSS Classes not displaying in my HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the chat bubbles found [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/default.css) in my own page and have been unable to get any kind of CSS to work on my page except for the code below:

```
form .error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFCC;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00;
    max-width:250px;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:arial;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    border-radius:6px;
}
.bubble:after,
.bubble:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.bubble:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 204, 0);
    border-right-color: #FFFFCC;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.bubble:before {
    border-color: rgba(255, 204, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: #FFCC00;
    border-width: 16px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

I am trying to style a `div` element and have tried numerous classes found in the Pure CSS Speech Bubble file referenced above, but for some reason the only class that appears as I want is the `bubble` class. Everything else simply displays as plain text. I've refreshed the page numerous times. Below is where I try to style the div as a chat bubble. Currently I am trying to use the right triangle variation from the link provided.

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="container" id='chatbox'>


                <div class = "triangle-right" th:each="message:${messages}">
                        <p th:text="${message.contents}"></p>
                        <p class="text-muted" th:text="'-' + ${message.sender}"></p>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                 <div class="input-group">
                 <form th:action="@{/sendmessage}" th:object="${message}" name="messageform" >
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="messageInput" rows="3" th:field="*{contents}" name="chatmessage"></textarea>

                  <!--<span class="input-group-btn">-->
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick='encrypt(' document.getElementById('messageInput').value + ','+ key +');'>Send</button>
                 <!-- </span>-->
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

My references:

```
<!-- Jquery base for validation and bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery validation plugin -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery validation rules for this page -->
<script src="../javascript/validation.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap css and required javascript files -->
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Style to make the warnings red and chat bubbles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css"/>
```

As mentioned, the bubble class works perfectly, but nothing else shows as anything other than plain (and muted) text. Any help is appreciated.

I am using Bootstrap version 3.2.0 as additional information, however I include the styles in this file below my Bootstrap references.

Comment: If you posted a bit more of your HTML, that might help pinpoint your issue. Is your CSS linked to your HTML properly?

Comment: I don't see your div using the class name "bubble" or any of it's variants

Comment: I am instead using the class "triangle-right" as it's not working. But this is where I call `bubble` class. I will update my code to include more of the HTML.